# Java not outputting or requesting keyboard input

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I am having trouble getting my java code to properly output the required results. Not to mention that my System.out.Println isn't prompting for input. All my code is good with no errors. However it just doesn't seem to output anything or request an input.

```
//Author Adam Duffy
package test1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {
public static void main(String [ ] args){}
public String DEF_EMP_NUM = "NO_EMP_NUM";
public double DEF_RATE_PER_HOUR = 20.0;
public double DEF_OVER_TIME_RATE = 40.0;
public double DEF_RATE_HOURS_PER_WEEK = 1.5;

private String empNum;
private double ratePerHour;
private double baseHrsPerWeek;
private double overTimeRate;
// no arg constructor setting width and length to default of 1

public Employee() {
    empNum = DEF_EMP_NUM;
    ratePerHour = DEF_RATE_PER_HOUR;
    baseHrsPerWeek = DEF_RATE_HOURS_PER_WEEK;
    overTimeRate = DEF_OVER_TIME_RATE;
}
// all arg constructor

public Employee(String empNum, float ratePerHour, float baseHrsPerWeek, int overTimeRate) {
    this.empNum = empNum;
    this.ratePerHour = ratePerHour;
    this.baseHrsPerWeek = baseHrsPerWeek;
    this.overTimeRate = overTimeRate;

}

//setters
public void setempNum(String empNum) {
    this.empNum = empNum;

}

public String getempNum() {
    return this.empNum;
}
//methods

public double getratePerHour() {
    return ratePerHour;
}

public void setratePerHour(float ratePerHour) {
    this.ratePerHour = ratePerHour;
}

public double getoverTimeRate() {
    return overTimeRate;
}

public int setoverTimeRate(int overTimeRate) {
    this.overTimeRate = overTimeRate;
    return overTimeRate;
}

public double getbaseHrsPerWeek() {
    return baseHrsPerWeek;
}

public void setbaseHrsPerWeek(float baseHrsPerWeek) {
    this.baseHrsPerWeek = baseHrsPerWeek;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString()
            + "\n["
            + "\nbaseHrsPerWeek = " + baseHrsPerWeek
            + "\noverTimeRate = " + overTimeRate
            + "\nratePerHour = " + ratePerHour
            + "\nempNum = " + empNum
            + "\n]";
}

public double calcWeeksPay(int hours) {
    return this.ratePerHour * this.baseHrsPerWeek;
    /*@param hours
    @return 
     */

}

{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    int myNum[] = new int[5];
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < myNum.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        myNum[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < myNum.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("The number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        System.out.print(myNum[i] + "\n+");

        for (int e = 1; e <= i; e++) {
            sum = sum + e;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
}
```

I just can't seem to get it to work. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. If I could get some advice, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Take the stuff at the end of the class `{ Scanner ... }` and put in `main` where it belongs

Comment: public static void main(String [ ] args){} just executes... nothing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Updated peice of code , which will accept and print the number on console.

```
public class Employee {
public static void main(String [ ] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int myNum[] = new int[5];
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < myNum.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        myNum[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < myNum.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("The number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        System.out.print(myNum[i] + "\n+");

        for (int e = 1; e <= i; e++) {
            sum = sum + e;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
public String DEF_EMP_NUM = "NO_EMP_NUM";
public double DEF_RATE_PER_HOUR = 20.0;
public double DEF_OVER_TIME_RATE = 40.0;
public double DEF_RATE_HOURS_PER_WEEK = 1.5;

private String empNum;
private double ratePerHour;
private double baseHrsPerWeek;
private double overTimeRate;
```

// no arg constructor setting width and length to default of 1

```
public Employee() {
    empNum = DEF_EMP_NUM;
    ratePerHour = DEF_RATE_PER_HOUR;
    baseHrsPerWeek = DEF_RATE_HOURS_PER_WEEK;
    overTimeRate = DEF_OVER_TIME_RATE;
}
```

// all arg constructor

```
public Employee(String empNum, float ratePerHour, float baseHrsPerWeek, int overTimeRate) {
    this.empNum = empNum;
    this.ratePerHour = ratePerHour;
    this.baseHrsPerWeek = baseHrsPerWeek;
    this.overTimeRate = overTimeRate;

}

//setters
public void setempNum(String empNum) {
    this.empNum = empNum;

}

public String getempNum() {
    return this.empNum;
}
```

//methods

```
public double getratePerHour() {
    return ratePerHour;
}

public void setratePerHour(float ratePerHour) {
    this.ratePerHour = ratePerHour;
}

public double getoverTimeRate() {
    return overTimeRate;
}

public int setoverTimeRate(int overTimeRate) {
    this.overTimeRate = overTimeRate;
    return overTimeRate;
}

public double getbaseHrsPerWeek() {
    return baseHrsPerWeek;
}

public void setbaseHrsPerWeek(float baseHrsPerWeek) {
    this.baseHrsPerWeek = baseHrsPerWeek;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString()
            + "\n["
            + "\nbaseHrsPerWeek = " + baseHrsPerWeek
            + "\noverTimeRate = " + overTimeRate
            + "\nratePerHour = " + ratePerHour
            + "\nempNum = " + empNum
            + "\n]";
}

public double calcWeeksPay(int hours) {
    return this.ratePerHour * this.baseHrsPerWeek;
/*@param hours
@return
 */
 }
}
```

Problem was that you were not having anything in the **psvm** method and below piece of code

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int myNum[] = new int[5];
        int i;
        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < myNum.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
            myNum[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < myNum.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("The number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
            System.out.print(myNum[i] + "\n+");

            for (int e = 1; e <= i; e++) {
                sum = sum + e;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
```

Which takes the input and print it on console was not having any calling code. it was just a inside the block of code. i just moved it inside the **main** method and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help.